# Unable to load excel file using Microsoft.Office > interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

In my WPF application I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to import data from excel file. I have been using this code for last couple of months and it has been working just fine for me. Today all of a sudden when I ran the utility I got the following error.

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

I had originally Office 2013 installed but 2 months ago I uninstalled and installed the 2007 version. Everything was working fine until now.

I have read on different posts to delete the registry entry corresponding to the above IID. I have tried doing that but no help. I uninstalled/repaired Office as well but no help.

I have tried to register the Microsoft.Office.interop.excel.dll using regasm.exe as well but again no luck. Whats the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried to search `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` under `HKRT\TypeLib` and delete the 2013 version

Comment: it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: What is full  path of HKRT\typeLib i cant find it!!! is it under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?

Answer (score -2):

I had a some problems with Interop. then I switched to Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 don't know if it helps, but I found it to be much more stable.